# Make a number more probable to result from random

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm using `x = numpy.random.rand(1)` to generate a random number between 0 and 1. How do I make it so that `x > .5` is 2 times more probable than `x < .5`?

Comment: @Jodrell it **is** random. Just not evenly distributed random.

Comment: You need to specify what sort of probability distribution you are looking for - there are infinitely many possible distributions where *p(x > 0.5) = 2*p(x < 0.5)*.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's a fitting name!

Just do a little manipulation of the inputs.  First set `x` to be in the range from `0` to `1.5`.

```
x = numpy.random.uniform(1.5)
```

`x` has a `2/3` chance of being greater than `0.5` and `1/3` chance being smaller.  Then if `x` is greater than `1.0`, subtract `.5` from it

```
if x >= 1.0:
    x = x - 0.5
```

Comment: .May need to be `>=` if the range is exclusive at the end

Comment: would it make a difference?

Answer (score 20):

This is overkill for you, but it's good to know an actual method for generating a random number with any probability density function (pdf).

You can do that by subclassing [scipy.stat.rv_continuous](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy-stats-rv-continuous), provided you do it correctly. You will have to have a normalized pdf (so that its integral is 1). If you don't, numpy will automatically adjust the range for you. In this case, your pdf has a value of 2/3 for x<0.5, and 4/3 for x>0.5, with a support of [0, 1) (support is the interval over which it's nonzero):

```
import scipy.stats as spst
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipdb


def pdf_shape(x, k):
    if x < 0.5:
        return 2/3.
    elif 0.5 <= x and x < 1:
        return 4/3.
    else:
        return 0.


class custom_pdf(spst.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, k):
        return pdf_shape(x, k)

instance = custom_pdf(a=0, b=1)

samps = instance.rvs(k=1, size=10000)

plt.hist(samps, bins=20)
plt.show()
```

[image: Example histogram]

Comment: I wanted to show that it opens a window for you, it isn't just automatically saved somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

```
tmp = random()
if tmp < 0.5: tmp = random()
```

is pretty easy way to do it

ehh I guess this is 3x as likely ... thats what i get for sleeping through that class I guess

```
from random import random,uniform

def rand1():
    tmp = random()
    if tmp < 0.5:tmp = random()
    return tmp
def rand2():
    tmp = uniform(0,1.5)
    return tmp if tmp <= 1.0 else tmp-0.5

sample1 = []
sample2 = []
for i in range(10000):
    sample1.append(rand1()>=0.5)
    sample2.append(rand2()>=0.5)

print sample1.count(True) #~ 75% 
print sample2.count(True) #~ 66% <- desired i believe :)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be 3 times more likely for a number greater than .5? I do like this way, though

Comment: I believe it would be 2x as likely to be 0.5 or greater my tests indicate ~ 75% of the time it is, which I guess is 3x as likely .... good maths :P

Comment: hmmm repeated tests(just populating a biggish list) show the other solution (rand(1.5) to result in 0.5 or greater only about 50% of the time .... which seems strange ...

Comment: I dont understand why i am not getting 66% success in rand2 ... please someone enlighten me :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley this is actually a variation of the logic behind the [Monty Hall Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem). What you're doing gives a 25% chance that < 0.5 will come up. Half the time you'll get > 0.5, and it'll be true. The _other_ half of the time, half of _that_ time it'll be > 0.5 and true. The _other_ half of that half it'll be false.

Comment: yeah I understand why my answer gives ~ 75%/25% ... i dont understand why the other solution does not seem to give the expected ~66/33%

Comment: ok Im dumb random.rand only gives an int ... it needs to be a uniform random to get the expected 66%

Comment: Minor nitpick. For a half-open range, it should be `return tmp if tmp < 1.0 ...`, _not_ `<=`.

Answer (score 3):

First off, `numpy.random.rand(1)` doesn't return a *value* in the `[0,1)` range (half-open, includes zero but not one), it returns an *array of size one,* containing values in that range, with the upper end of the range having nothing to do with the argument passed in.

The function you're probably after is the uniform distribution one, `numpy.random.uniform()` since this will allow an arbitrary upper range.

And, to make the upper half twice as likely is a relatively simple matter.

Take, for example, a random number generator `r(n)` which returns a uniformly distributed integer in the range `[0,n)`. All you need to do is adjust the values to change the distribution:

```
x = r(3)     # 0, 1 or 2, @ 1/3 probability each
if x == 2:
    x = 1    # Now either 0 (@ 1/3) or 1 (@ 2/3)
```

Now the chances of getting zero are 1/3 while the chances of getting one are 2/3, basically what you're trying to achieve with your floating point values.

So I would simply get a random number in the range `[0,1.5)`, then subtract 0.5 if it's greater than or equal to one.

```
x = numpy.random.uniform(high=1.5)
if x >= 1: x -= 0.5
```

Since the original distribution should be even across the `[0,1.5)` range, the subtraction should make `[0.5,1.0)` twice as likely (and `[1.0,1.5)` impossible), while keeping the distribution even within each section (`[0,0.5)` and `[0.5,1)`):

```
 [0.0,0.5)  [0.5,1.0)  [1.0,1.5)  before
<---------><---------><--------->
 [0.0,0.5)  [0.5,1.0)  [0.5,1.0)  after
```

Comment: @Blackhole, it was pretty much posted at the same time so the answer of AZ didn't actually exist when I started (this happens quite often). Once I saw it, it had an error in the distribution (which has since been fixed in the code if not the text), which is why I didn't delete mine. In any case, I believe there's extra explanation in mine which makes it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a "mixture model" approach where you split the process into two steps: first, decide whether to take option A or B, where B is twice as likely as A; then, if you chose A, return a random number between 0.0 and 0.5, else if you chose B, return one between 0.5 and 1.0.

In the example, the randint randomly returns 0, 1, or 2, so the `else` case is twice as likely as the `if` case.

```
  m = numpy.random.randint(3)
  if m==0:
    x = numpy.random.uniform(0.0, 0.5)
  else:
    x = numpy.random.uniform(0.5, 1.0)
```

This is a little more expensive (two random draws instead of one) but it can generalize to more complicated distributions in a fairly straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a more fluid randomness, you can just square the output of the random function

(and subtract it from 1 to make `x > 0.5` more probable instead of `x < 0.5`).

```
x = 1 - sqr(numpy.random.rand(1))
```

Comment: By fluid, I assume you mean "differently to what was specified" :-) I can't see how that would make the upper half twice as probable, in fact I suspect it introduces a continuously variable probability weighted towards the upper end.