# Make a random number more probable in python

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I'm using `numpy.random.rand(1)` to generate a number between 0-1 and the values of `a` and `b` change depending on what the number is. How can I make the probability of `x > .5`  and `x < .5` be proportional to `a` and `b`? So if `a` is 75 and `b` is 15 then the probability of `x > .5` is 5 times more probable than x < .5. I'm unsure as to what codes to use to assign probabilities. This is what I have:

```
a = 100
b = 100
while True:
    x = numpy.random.rand(1)            
    print x
    if x < .5:                         
        a = a + 10                     
        b = b - 10                     
        print a
        print b
    if x > .5:                         
        b = b + 10                   
        a = a - 10                     
        print a
        print b
    if b1 == 0:                         
        print a 
        break                         
    if b2 == 0:                         
        print b 
        break
```

Comment: This is ill-posed. There are infinitely many probability distributions with the property that P(X>.5) = 5*P(X<.5).

Comment: Have I seen this question before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a number more probable to result from random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462265/make-a-number-more-probable-to-result-from-random)

Comment: I've seen you ask this exact same question at least 3 times now (one was heavily downvoted and subsequently deleted). What was wrong with the previous answers?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would have numpy generate a number between 1 and 100 then assign based on that. I.e. (pusdocode)

```
if rand(100) => 50: a=0 
else: a=1
```

then all you have to do is changed the 50 to whatever the % you want. I can elaborate further if that is confusing.

```
def get_rand_value(a, b):
    if rand(100) => a:
        return True
    else:
        return 1
a = 100
b = 100 

while True:
    x = get_rand_value(a, b)
    print x
    if x < .5:                         
        a = a + 10                     
        b = b - 10                     
        print a
        print b
    if x > .5:                         
        b = b + 10                   
        a = a - 10                     
        print a
        print b
    if b1 == 0:                         
        print a 
        break                         
    if b2 == 0:                         
        print b 
        break
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but the values of a and b constantly change in the loop, is there a way to make it so that the probability also constantly changes depending on their values?

Comment: You would make a function that gets called each loop that has the values as an input.

Comment: I put it in your example for you. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd make two calls to random: One to calculate a random number between 0 and 0.5 and a second to determine if the number should be above 0.5.

For example;

```
a = 100
b = 100
x = numpy.random.rand(1)/2.0

proportion = a/(1.0*b+a)
if numpy.random.rand(1) > proportion:
    x += 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

what a fitting name.

```
ratio = a/b

x = numpy.random.uniform(0.5 + ratio*0.5)
```

now you have a numbers distributed between 0 and the ratio multiplied by 0.5.  With uniform distribution, the ratio between the population of numbers greater than 0.5 and the population lower than 0.5 is the desired ratio.

now we just need to broadcast those ranges to be between 0.5 and 1.0.

```
if x >= 0.5:
    x = x - math.trunc(x) 
    if int(str(number-int(x))[1:]) < 5:
        x += 0.5
```